# Bundling failed ... ... none of these files exist; missing firebase\index

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I've started experimenting with React Native and Firebase but I can't seem to run it without missing files:

```
    Android Bundling failed 597ms 
While trying to resolve module `firebase` from file `C:\Users\wootk\Documents\GitHub\React-and-rNative\React Native\React Native, Firebase v9, authen
tication and firestore\FirebaseAuthApp\firebase\firebaseConfig.js`, the package `C:\Users\wootk\Documents\GitHub\React-and-rNative\React Native\React
 Native, Firebase v9, authentication and firestore\FirebaseAuthApp\node_modules\firebase\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specif
ies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\wootk\Documents\GitHub\React-and-rNative-ALL-PROJECTS\React Native\React Native, Firebase v9, auth
entication and firestore\FirebaseAuthApp\node_modules\firebase\index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:


  * C:\Users\wootk\Documents\GitHub\React-and-rNative\React Native\React Native, Firebase v9, authentication and firestore\FirebaseAuthApp\node_modul
es\firebase\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.
json|.json)
  * C:\Users\wootk\Documents\GitHub\React-and-rNative\React Native\React Native, Firebase v9, authentication and firestore\FirebaseAuthApp\node_modul
es\firebase\index\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.n
ative.json|.json)
```

Dependencies from `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "12": "^1.0.2",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.5",
    "npm": "^8.4.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
```

and the `firebaseConfig.js` is just an initializeApp and getAuth exported to `App.js`

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth/";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // Config from Firebase project setup ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

`App.js` imports:

```
import { auth } from "./firebase/firebaseConfig";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
```

Auth is linked to an auth register function...

```
const RegisterUser = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        console.log(userCredential);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

...but gives the above error as explained before

> Bundling failed While trying to resolve module `firebase` ...

I have also tried to reinstall Firebase and reset the cache

It could be because of how Firebase was installed, because npm seems to break it so it doesn't install everything in the `./node_modules/firebase` but it's ran with `expo install firebase` so it should theoretically work. Why is there missing files and how do I get them to install?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. You just need to make some change inside `package.json` file:

using

```
"firebase": "^8.2.3"
```

instead of

```
"firebase": "^9.6.5"
```

and ther run `npm install`

and don't forget to change syntax to ‍‍‍‍**v8**